# RoR: what do I add to routes.rb for this to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have an application where a user can make microposts. But enter one into the form and press post, it says No route matches [POST] "/users/1". Here is my current routes.rb file .

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :comments

    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy] do
    resources :comments

  end
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'


  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
```

and this is the output when I run rake routes:

```
user_comments GET    /users/:user_id/comments(.:format)                    comments#index
                       POST   /users/:user_id/comments(.:format)                    comments#create
      new_user_comment GET    /users/:user_id/comments/new(.:format)                comments#new
     edit_user_comment GET    /users/:user_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)           comments#edit
          user_comment GET    /users/:user_id/comments/:id(.:format)                comments#show
                       PUT    /users/:user_id/comments/:id(.:format)                comments#update
                       DELETE /users/:user_id/comments/:id(.:format)                comments#destroy
        following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format)                        users#following
        followers_user GET    /users/:id/followers(.:format)                        users#followers
                 users GET    /users(.:format)                                      users#index
                       POST   /users(.:format)                                      users#create
              new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                  users#new
             edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                             users#edit
                  user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                  users#show
                       PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                  users#update
                       DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                  users#destroy
              sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                                   sessions#create
           new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                               sessions#new
               session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                               sessions#destroy
    micropost_comments GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                       POST   /microposts/:micropost_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                       PUT    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                       DELETE /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            microposts POST   /microposts(.:format)                                 microposts#create
             micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format)                             microposts#destroy
         relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)                              relationships#create
          relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)                          relationships#destroy
                  root        /                                                     static_pages#home
                signup        /signup(.:format)                                     users#new
                signin        /signin(.:format)                                     sessions#new
               signout DELETE /signout(.:format)                                    sessions#destroy
                  help        /help(.:format)                                       static_pages#help
                 about        /about(.:format)                                      static_pages#about
               contact        /contact(.:format)                                    static_pages#contact
```

I guess what I really need is for [POST] users/:id to route to microposts#create, but I don't know the syntax for it.

p.s. If I add post post "users/:id", :controller => "users/update", I get the error:

```
ArgumentError (missing :action):
  config/routes.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
  config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

here is the form which is talking to the controller (i think)

```
<%= form_for :micropost do |f| %>

  <div class="field no-indent">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's something else you want to buy?" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'micropost[kind]', "purchase" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form_for you just need to specify url. I think this should work.
    <%= form_for :micropost, :html => {:method => :post, :url => microposts_path} do |f| %>

```
  <div class="field no-indent">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's something else you want to buy?" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'micropost[kind]', "purchase" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Also let me know what is html output. In form_for :html parameter is given as a hashmap, where key are form attributes and values are attribute values.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using put request. put method="PUT", in mean time i will find this problem.

Comment: how can I tell it to use put instead of post?

Comment: how you are hiting the controller, through link, through ajax, simple html form, etc. Please tell or add its code to your question.

Comment: I tried it and it still gave the same error. Then I changed the line you added to routes to put "users/:id", :controller => "users/update" (i think thats what you meant) and it gave the error No route matches [GET] "/"

Comment: actually It now give the error no route matches [GET] "/" no matter whether I use put or post in the routes.rb file

Comment: can you check your html code of form and see what is the method there.

Comment: Hi just try the next edit, sry i am not that much familiar with form_for, just trying to help you.  Give a try, i think that should help.

Comment: sorry, I am trying to change the micropost form to put instead of post. I keep getting server errors though so I cant check the html to see if it worked. Why do you think put is better than post in this case?

Comment: I am using <%= form_for :micropost {:method => :put} do |f| %>. Is this what you had in mind? It gives me a syntax error.

Comment: just see the edit,i've not used block quote and try again, please try again.

Comment: ok interesting. It seems like that worked, but it is routing me to update my user info (which would make sense according to the routes input). What I need is for that to update my users show page to include the micropost that I just created. Would this involve changing users/update to microposts/create?

Comment: when you need it to route to user create, why you are sending user_id in url. In 'user/1'; '1' is the user_id.

Comment: if that worked please vote up and accept. Your accept percentage is less and this may be the reason many people didn't answer your question. Always accept and upvote the answer, which satisfies you.

Comment: sorry I was away for a little while. But it didn't work. I don't want it to route to user create. I want it to route to micropost create (update the users show page to include the new micropost, not update the users information). Additionally, I just realized that this only happens when I dont add post "users/:id", :controller => "users/update" to the routes.rb file. When I do, I still get the missing :action error

Comment: also when I inspect the html output, it seems that the micropost form is still a post method. how can this be?

Comment: please don't add anything to routes.rb. There is doing some syntax error for that. Will let you know about it soon. Actually I understood your problem, micropost is nested in resource. You want it for micropost and it is giving you user. I will tr to find the solution.

Comment: also can you explain more about when to use put and when to use post? Sorry I am asking for so much, you have been very helpful

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16853/discussion-between-bigboy1337-and-paritosh-singh)

Comment: no its not a problem, don't say sorry, something we are missing, I'll let you know what is that. Well whenever we use resources in rails by default, it will use different kind on request on different controllers. On update controller it uses 'put' request. You have given me output of "rake routes"; in that you can see the GET, POST words. They state that with which request a url should be hit to go to that controller. If you can see url for "comment#new" and "comment#update" are same. Its only type of request that distinguishes whether it is for update or for new controller.